# Lock other threads until first thread finished

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, locking

I have a scenario where first thread gets an authentication token from a Web API. I want all other threads to wait until we get the authentication token and save that authentication token in database. Once the authentication token is saved in a database, all other thread use that authentication token and work as normally as they do or we can say that disable the lock for all other threads.

```
private object _dataLock = new object();

lock(_dataLock)
{
    Get Authentication Token

    Save it in database
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could do this with a condition variable or semaphore.

Comment: @PiRocks : Can you give me small example how can we do that?

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. Why use threading at all, if you block all threads? Why not simply do the authentication in the main foreground thread?